# Remove rows whose sum is equal to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example I have a simple table with values:

```
|Code|Value|
|x1  |5    |
|x2  |-5   |
|x3  |-5   |
|x4  |5    |
|x5  |5    |
```

I need to remove rows whose sum is equal to 0.
I.e. for this example I'll want to remove rows with codes x1 and x2, x3 and x4 OR x1 and x2, x3 and x5 - it doesn't matter in my case.

It sounds like simple task, but I can't do it.
I can't even understand how to select the items I want to delete.

I tried to join table on itself like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Code AS Code1,
    t2.Code AS Code2
FROM TableX AS t1
JOIN TableX As t2
ON t1.Code <> t2.Code
    AND t1.Value + t2.Value = 0
ORDER BY t1.Code
```

Result:

```
|Code1|Code2
|x1   |x2
|x1   |x3
|x2   |x1
|x2   |x4
|x2   |x5
|x3   |x1
|x3   |x4
|x3   |x5
|x4   |x2
|x4   |x3
|x5   |x2
|x5   |x3
```

But I don't understand what should I do next.

I'm not lazy - I tried different variants - with GROUP BY and MIN, with ROW_NUMBER() but unfortunately I can't understand how can I select rows to delete and leave others?

Comment: this is difficult, as x1 would be joined to all other possible codes and so on..even if one combination gives a zero sum, the other combinations might not,so you wouldn't get the expected result.

Comment: Do we only need to identify and delete **pairs** of rows that sum to zero, rather than arbitrarily many combinations of rows that sum to zero (e.g. one row is +5, one row is -3, one row is -2)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, only pairs of rows.

Comment: What determines the pair you want to remove? You use the example of removing either x1 and x2 or x3 and x4, but what about x1 and x3 or x2 and x5?  Since there is going to be 1 '5' value left over, it could be either x1, x4, or x5,

Comment: @dfundako - I interpreted the OPs "it doesn't matter in my case." literally

Comment: @dfundako It seems that I poorly explained problem. Sorry. In this example I want to get one row (x1, x4 or x5) as a result. It does not matter which line it will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to cover it, I believe:

```
declare @t table (Code varchar(20) not null, Value int not null)
insert into @t(Code,Value) values
('x1',5  ),
('x2',-5 ),
('x3',-5 ),
('x4',5  ),
('x5',5  )

;With Ordered as (
    select
        Code,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY Code) rn
    from
        @t
), Pairs as (
    select
        o1.Code c1,
        o2.Code c2
    from
        Ordered o1
            inner join
        Ordered o2
            on
                o1.Value = -o2.Value and
                o1.rn = o2.rn
    where
        o1.Value > 0
)
delete from t from @t t where exists (
    select * from Pairs p where p.c1 = t.Code or
                                p.c2 = t.Code)

select * from @t
```

Result:

```
Code                 Value
-------------------- -----------
x5                   5
```

This works be deciding to give unique row numbers to each row, based on what their `Value` is. We then pair the rows based on finding rows with equal row numbers but opposite values.

It may be instructive to `select * from Ordered` or `select * from Pairs` rather than the `delete`, if you want to see how it's working.

Comment: Wow! It's working!
I have not thought of using row number to JOIN. =(
Thank you!